# Can't understand exactly the pointers in 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have done something by looking to the internet but something is missing here is my code

```
void draw_way(int *arr,int lenght_row,int lenght_column) {
int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
for (s1 = 0; s1 < lenght_row; s1++)
{
    for (s2 = 0; s2 < lenght_column; s2++) {
        if (*((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2) == 1)
        {
            printf("S");
        }
        else if (*((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2) == 2)
        {
            printf("G");
        }
        else if(*((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2) == 3)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        else if (*((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2) == 4)
        {
            printf(".");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

it is actually printing a maze but is is not important. The thing I want to understand is why ı had to use `*((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2)` why this is not working if ı use `*(*(arr+s1)+s2)` what *'lenght_row'* does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any array or pointer `arr` and index `i`, the expression `*(arr + i)` is exactly equal to `arr[i]`.

If we do this translation for `*(*(arr+s1)+s2)` that would be `(arr[s1])[s2]` (or `arr[s1][s2]`). Since `arr` isn't a pointer to a pointer (or array of arrays) then `arr[s1][s2]` doesn't make sense.

Instead you kind of emulate a 2d array (array of arrays) using a array (whose first element is pointed to by `arr`) and use arithmetic to calculate the single index into this array.

This is very common for dynamically allocated memory, where instead of using a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) (using pointers to pointers) you use a single contiguous area or memory.

---

It might be easier to understand with an illustration...

Lets say we want a 2d array of 2 by 3 elements. We can create it using dynamic allocation as a jagged array:

```
int **arr;
arr = malloc(2 * sizeof *arr);  // First dimension
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    arr[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof *arr[i]);  // Second dimension
```

Since we have multiple allocations, there's no locality in the array, `arr[0][2]` might not be followed by `arr[1][0]`. Locality and having the 2d array being contiguous could be good for some algorithm and use-cases.

A contiguous 2d array would be an array of arrays like

```
int arr[2][3];
```

but this is harder to handle dynamically, so instead we allocate a single  contiguous memory area of `2 * 3` elements:

```
int *arr;
arr = malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof *arr);
```

Unfortunately this can't be indexed in the same intuitive way as a jagged array or array of arrays (i.e. `arr[0][1]` isn't possible). But with some clever arithmetic it is possible: `arr[row_index * row_length + column_index]` will be like `arr[row_index][column_index]` (for a jagged array or array of arrays).

Answer (score 1):

arr is a flat array, not a multi-dimensional array.  It emulates a mult-dimensional array by way of passing in the grid size.  So, if it was 5x2, then arr as a flat array would be 10 integers long, not an array of 5 rows of another array of 2 columns.

Hence, it uses simple pointer arithmetic to emulate the r,c dimensions by way of the flat array index calculation

`((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2)`

Comment: BTW, the code variable names do not make sense from the standpoint of "length_row" should be set to "number of columns" (which, I guess technically is the length of a row), and similarly, "length_column" should be set to "number of rows", which, technically is correct.  I would recommend changing those to num_rows and num_columns so it is much less confusing.

Comment: Also, the compiler quietly does the same thing while working with "real" 2D arrays. Unlike "arrays of arrays" (which are not always contigious, and the address is calculated by taking a pointer from first array and using it as the base for second array, which takes additional memory access operation instead of a simple multiplication operation).

Comment: while saying _arr is a flat array, not a multi-dimensional array_ did you mean _you are not pointing 2 dimensional array. It is just an array_

Comment: @nbr yes, that is what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

For starters the expression in if-else statements like this

```
if (*((arr + s1 * lenght_row) + s2) == 1)
```

is incorrect. There should be

```
if (*((arr + s1 * lenght_column) + s2) == 1)
```

The parameter arr declared like

```
int *arr
```

has the type `int *`. So dereferencing the pointer like `*arr` you will get an object of the type int for which you may not apply the dereferncing operator.

So this expression

```
*(*(arr+s1)+s2)
```

is incorrect. The sub-expression `*(arr+s1)` has the type int. So the second use of the operator * produce a compilation error.

In the shown function there is emulated a two dimensional array using a pointer to a one-dimensional array. That is the one-dimensional array is logically split into  chunks by length_column elements.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW_LENGTH      2
#define COLUMN_LENGTH   3

void display( const int *arr, size_t row_length, size_t column_length )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row_length; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < column_length; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *( arr + i * column_length + j ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[ROW_LENGTH * COLUMN_LENGTH] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    display( arr, ROW_LENGTH, COLUMN_LENGTH );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Comment: don't need to do my code works perfect but like ı said ı couldn't understand what ı have done. In kind of funny way changing row_lenght and column_lenght doesnt effect anything

Comment: @NBR  An invalid code arises questions and confuses readers. You should always provide a correct code that users were concentrated on the problem..

Answer (score 0):

if you reduce number of paranthises it will easier to understand: `if (*(arr + s1 * lenght_row + s2) == 2)`

2D array has `c` columns and `r` rows. They are stored in the memory continuously  row0 then row 1 them row2 ...

So to access the particular element (row, column) you need multiply row by 'r' (whics is how many elements we hae in the row and add column.